# Using graphics in code blocks but no output

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

I am a newbie regarding the use of graphics in programming. I have an experience with the non-graphics program though. I am trying to run a graphics program in code blocks. The code compiles successfully but the output is not displayed. I have copied the code from the web.

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
   int gdriver=DETECT,gmode;
   initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "c:\turboc3\bgi");

   //for head
   ellipse(320,95,360,0,25,20);
   line(298,85,341,85);
   circle(310,90,2);
   circle(330,90,2);
   arc(320,100,200,-20,10);

   //for neck
   line(313,115,313,125);
   line(328,115,328,125);

   //For centre part
   arc(320,225,72,107,100);
   line(290,129,290,200);
   line(350,129,350,200);
   line(290,193,350,193);
   line(290,200,350,200);

   //for legs
   line(290,200,285,280);
   line(320,225,305,280);
   line(322,225,335,280);
   line(350,200,355,280);

   //for right hand
   line(290,129,255,165);
   line(255,165,290,200);
   line(290,149,275,165);
   line(275,165,290,182);

   //for left hand
   line(350,129,385,165);
   line(385,165,350,200);
   line(350,149,365,165);
   line(365,165,350,182);

   //for shoes
   line(285,280,275,287);
   line(275,287,305,287);
   line(305,280,305,287);

   line(335,280,335,287);
   line(335,287,365,287);
   line(355,280,365,287);

   //for name
   settextstyle(2,HORIZ_DIR,4);
   outtextxy(293,150,"The Crazy");
   outtextxy(292,160,"Programmer");

   getch();
   closegraph();
}
```

This is the code I derived from [this](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2011/05/c-program-to-print-man-using-graphics.html) site. 
I have attached the [output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pEah.png) in case you wanna see my output.

Comment: Frame challenge: Unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise, you should absolutely not bother with Turbo C and it's libraries like `graphics.h` and `conio.h`. They are well over 20 years out of date at this point.

Comment: Would you mind dropping some suggestions regarding the graphics usage in code blocks?

Comment: One relatively simple, relatively modern graphics library for C you could use is [SDL2](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Introduction). Also, delete everything related to Turbo C and unbookmark everything that told you that you should have anything to do with it.

Comment: I am working with C++. Hope this one will work. And thank you

Comment: Also please read the [C++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) for a further explanation on Turbo C and what you should use instead (this is what you're using right now).

Comment: I want to learn the use of graphics in C++ from scratch. Please recommend me some of the best sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the path of BGI in initgraph() function.

```
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"\\Path to CodeBlocks Lib Folder");
```

and then run it.

I hope it will work